# iOS: Bluetooth Low Energy: One physical device, different services for different connections -> Trouble?

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, service-discovery

I am having an issue concerning Bluetooth Low Energy. I am using an iPhone (iOS 6.1) and an Nordic board using the nRF51822 chip.
I am currently developing a system where the iPhone and the nRF51822 connect using certain services, then disconnect and reconnect again. However, on the second connection, the nRF51822 uses different services from the first connection.

The problem is that on the second connection, the iPhone discovers the former services of the first connection. I have tested with a TI CC2540 development board and it discovers the new services well. The only solution I have found is to put the central manager to nil and allocate it again to make it work. Nevertheless, it seems kind of a dirty solution, is there a standard (clean) way to deal with this kind of situation?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't do any bonding, but only pairing, then you would not have this issue.

If you do require bonding, then the best way to solve this problem is to use the Bond-manager that is in the SDK. If you are not using the [bond manager](https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/documentation/nrf51/4.4.0/html/group__ble__sdk__lib__bond__manager.html), you could try to use the [Service Changed](https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/documentation/nrf51/4.4.0/html/group___b_l_e___g_a_t_t_s___f_u_n_c_t_i_o_n_s.html#ga2c8c90d73fa27ba6691ad82b4a960adc) functionallity and set the start handle to 0x000C, and end handle to 0xFFFF. This would most likely trigger a rediscovery from the iOS, thus finding your new services and characteristics. The iOS would always look for service changed, and enable this in the peripheral.

If you have any Nordic related question, then you could post them at the Q&A forum located at https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/

BR
Pål

Answer (score 0):

Services and characteristics are cached on the iOS side when you initiate a pairing request with a ble device and discover services/characteristics. Don't do the pairing request if you're concerned about that. Then just pass in the array of services you actually want to discover (not nil).

(Side note: The whole thing of having the ble device controlling which services are seen to the iOS device seems really muddled..you should control that on the iOS side.)

Comment: Actually, I don't do any pairing request and the device is not stored in the paired device. I kind of think that iOS might have a problem. Another "bug" I found yesterday is that sometimes when I crash the BLE stack on the nRF51822, the iPhone won't be able (even if I kill my app and reboot the nRF51822) to discover any service again unless I reboot it... Kind of a pain in the &+! to debug...

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with this and my main development has been on the nrf51...sounds more likely to be a problem with your firmware